# Avada Live Builders deletes "\" backslash

Tags: wordpress, backslash

I am using KATEX plugin for WordPress. The plugin uses short-code and works fine in the WordPress default editor and Avada Builder (Avada is a WordPress theme). However, I have noticed that Avada Live Builder deletes all backslashes `\` from LaTeX equations, so typing the following equation:

`[latex]\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i[/latex]`

is rendered as

`[latex]bar{x} = frac{1}{n} sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i[/latex]`

I tried replacing the backslash with HTML entity `&#92;`, but no joy.

I am using WordPress 6.3 and Avada version 7.11.2

Answer (score 0):

**Disable Auto-Formatting:** Some page builders or visual editors might apply auto-formatting or auto-correction to the content, which can lead to unwanted modifications. In such cases, you could check if there are any settings within Avada Live Builder that control auto-formatting and disable them for the specific content block containing your equations.